# QUERY Function that pulls latest date from a group of data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have this data from a sheet1:

```
colA -- colB -- colC -- colD -- colE
user1 -- prodA -- 1mo -- 2020-05-01 -- 50
user1 -- prodA -- 1mo -- 2020-06-01 -- 50
user1 -- prodA -- 1mo -- 2020-07-01 -- 50
user1 -- prodA -- 1mo -- 2020-08-01 -- 50
user1 -- prodA -- 1mo -- 2020-09-01 -- 45
```

Then I need to just show up in sheet2 col A,B,C and the latest date from colD and the value of that row from colE. How can I pull that using QUERY?

Output:

```
user1 -- prodA -- 1mo -- 2020-09-01 -- 45
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:E,"select A,B,C,D,E order by D desc limit 1")
```

Order D by descending and limit 1.

To remove the headers, you can do this:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(Sheet1!A:E,"select A,B,C,D,E order by D desc limit 1"),2)
```

Or as a pure `QUERY`:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:E,"select A,B,C,D,E 
order by D desc 
limit 1
label A'',B'',C'',D'',E''")
```

Comment: Hi, it works for only 1 group of data, I have 3k+ rows, and my goal is to show that 1 line of that group for all the other groups, so every query has each selected line..

Comment: @Sarah Sorry, but your question only specified the one sheet with one data set and one row. You'll have to be more specific about how your sheets are set up and what you want.