# How to pivot 3-d table in google-sheets

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula

I have this table:

```
from_value - name - to_value
1             a        5
2             b        10
1             c        8
```

which I want to convert to this:

```
from_value   a   b    c
1:           5   0    8
2:           0   10   0
```

Is this possible to do this automatically somehow, as this is a 3-d pivoting.

Comment: This is a regular pivot table.

Comment: I think that the linked formulas do **not work** for this question. I believe it should be reopened. The solution is [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7bPo.png)

Comment: The answer is to use query with pivot. That's all. This should not be reopened. If OP has issues with implementing the solution, OP should ask a new question with error details and his attempts.

Comment: @TheMaster *"The answer is to use query with pivot. That's all."* I agree. But with a twist. Still. There are [even simpler uses of formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64052994) that are not -and shouldn't be- closed.

Comment: @marikamitsos I disagree. Changing count to sum is not a twist.  Your linked question should also be closed. If I had a suitable duplicate, it would be closed by now.

Comment: @TheMaster When mentioning the twist I was referring to the `0`'s. Of course   *"Changing count to sum is not a twist"*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that is not very nice (one of the formulas must be repeated by hand).
First to obtain the unique values of the first two columns:

```
A8 =SORT(UNIQUE(A1:A3))
B7 =TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE($B$1:$B$3)))
```

Than copy in all cells of the range:

```
B8:E10 =IFERROR(FILTER({$C$1:$C$3};{$A$1:$A$3}=INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C1";FALSE);{$B$1:$B$3}=INDIRECT("R7C"&COLUMN();FALSE));0)
```

[image]